# How to make a linkbutton onclick with parameters

Tags: c#, html, parameters, onclick, linkbutton

HTML :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_productImage" runat="server" Text="select"
   OnClick="viewProductImage('<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id") %>')"
   >
</asp:LinkButton>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void viewProductImage(object sender, EventArgs e, int id)
{ 
    //Load Product Image
}
```

Comment: sorry bad code post.

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_productImage" runat="server" Text="select" OnClick="viewProductImage('<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id")  %>')"></asp:LinkButton></td>

 protected void viewProductImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
                
        }

Comment: please, edit your code and put what is in your comment

Answer (score 9):

I see you're using a repeater, so you probably could use this code:

In your repeater template:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="_postsRepeater" runat="server" OnItemCommand="_postsRepeater_ItemCommand">
  <ItemTemplate><asp:LinkButton ID="_postDeleteLinkButton" runat="server" CommandName="DeletePost" CommandArgument="<%# ((Post)Container.DataItem).ID %>">Delete</asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then handle the repeater's ItemCommand event:

```
protected void _postsRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "DeletePost") // Replace DeletePost with the name of your command
    {
        // Get the passed parameter from e.CommandArgument
        // e.g. if passed an int use:
        // int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use CommandArgument property of linkbutton to pass parameters.

CommandArgument property:

Gets or sets an optional argument passed to the Command event handler along with the associated command name property.

[LinkButton Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton_members.aspx)

Comment: Yeah but it your using the linkbutton in a gridview template row you can't do that if I am not mistaken?

Comment: ahhh sorry brain fart. You'll need to do this to get the value ((LinkButton) sender).CommandArgument